# Running multiple for loops in batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I wrote a code that connects to 70 or more windows servers (list in sis.txt), identifies which is the correct certificate and copies it to the server. The filename of the certicate is "hostname.pfx", which is same as the output command of "hostname" + .pfx
The problem is, that I can use %%i only one time in this code. Currently, it will not run the 3rd line at all, or atleast will not save it's output into a variable called %filename%, because %%i is already allocated to something else. I also tried %%g but no joy. I wan't the output of 3rd line to be saved into a variable which I can then use in the 6th line (xcopy command). Since the output of hostname command would be the actual hostname (server1-global) then it would pick the correct certificate file (server1-global.pfx) to copy.
I know that this is probably an ass-backwards method, but it is the best I could come up with given that batch syntax and logic make my head hurt and nearly vomit.

```
FOR /F %%i IN (sis.txt) DO(
ECHO %%i
FOR /F %%i in ('PsExec.exe \\%%i -u myuser -p mypassword cmd /c hostname') do set filename=%%i
ECHO %filename%
START /Wait NET USE S: \\%%i\c$\transfer /USER:myuser mypassword
xcopy U:\files\%filename%.pfx /e /k /Y S:\
NET USE S: /Delete /Y
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /F %%i IN (sis.txt) DO (
 ECHO %%i
 FOR /F %%q in ('PsExec.exe \\%%i -u myuser -p mypassword cmd /c hostname') do (
  set filename=%%q
  ECHO %%q
  START /Wait NET USE S: \\%%i\c$\transfer /USER:myuser mypassword
  xcopy U:\files\%%q.pfx /e /k /Y S:\
  NET USE S: /Delete /Y
 )
)
```

This should fix your problem. The variable in the inner loop **must** be different from that in the outer, else batch (or any other language, for that matter) can't resolve which particular "%%i" you are referring to.

Unless you use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, the changing value of an environment variable is not available (easily).

Batch replaces any `%varname% with the value of`varname`at the time the command is **parsed**, so your use of`%filename% within a block statement (a parenthesised series of statements) is doomed. It will be replaced by the value of `filename` at the time the outer loop is parsed.

With a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` line, then the current value of `filename` could be accessed by using `!filename!`, but in the case you show, this is not necessary - `filename` is set to the value of the inner metavariable (I've changed that to `%%q`) - and `%%q` can be substituted in the expressions you've used (at least, the printable ones...)

Batch can also be sensitive to spaces - and a space is required before the `do` keyword of a `for` loop.

Now - if the value to be placed in filename/%%q contains spaces, this may need a little adjustment, but you haven' told us that, so I'll leave it as a simple caution.

---

Edited - need an extra pair of parentheses for the `do` part of `for..%%q...`. Without them, only the `set filename=%%q` is executed, not the block of statements up to and including the `net use ... /delete...`

Comment: I already tried to change the inner %%i to %%g - this is what happens:

´U:\TransferFilesToProbes>(
ECHO server1-global
 FOR /F %q in ('PsExec.exe \\server1-global -u myuser mypass cmd /c hostname') do set filename=%q
 ECHO %q
 START /Wait NET USE S: \\server1-global\c$\transfer /USER:myuser mypassword
 xcopy U:\files\%q.pfx /e /k /Y S:\
 NET USE S: /Delete /Y´

It changes %%q to %q without actually populating the variable with what is needed

Comment: you are right. Too bad that most machines from this list don't seem to be accepting logins using PsExec, saying that the handle is incorrect, but your solution, technically, is correct. Thank you.